# How to focus input when a user clicked on an input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, stylus

I've tried to create a search input component in react.js. In this component, I want to when a user clicked on the search icon, the input focus and its width increased by the css3 transition attribute.
This is a chunk of my code:

```
    <input className={"news-search-v2"} type="text" />
    <i className="material-icons"> search </i>
```

And the stylus code for my component

```
.news-search-v2
   width 0px
   transition: ease 0.5s all
   &:focus
      border-bottom solid 1px #5f6368
      width 300px
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare name attribute to the Input and wrap the icon in label element and provide "for" attribute to it whose value would be equal to name of the input : [Reason](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp)

```
<input name="search" className={"news-search-v2"} type="text" />
<label for="search"><i className="material-icons"> search </i></label>
```

to get this working in react. use "htmlFor" instead of "for" : [Reason](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor)

Answer (score 2):

`Arnav Yagnik` answer is correct, but not a `React` solution.

You can use `useRef` hook if your component is a functional.

```
import React from 'react';

const FocusExample = () => {
  const textInput = React.useRef(null);

  const setFocus = React.useCallback(() => { textInput.current.focus() });

  return (
    <>
      <input ref={textInput} className={"news-search-v2"} type="text" />
      <i className="material-icons" onClick={setFocus}> search </i>
    </>
  );
};
```

Or if you are using classed based view use `createRef`:

```
import React from 'react';

class FocusExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }

  setFocus = () => {
    this.textInput.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <input ref={this.textInput} className={"news-search-v2"} type="text" />
        <i className="material-icons" onClick={this.setFocus}> search </i>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```